# How to check if user is logged in using a streambuilder with null safe firebaseauth (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Before migrating to null safety, this code worked:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            User? user = snapshot.data;
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return SignInPage();
            }
            int currentTime = Timestamp.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
            usersReference.doc(user.uid).set(
                {"lastLoggedInCreate": currentTime}, SetOptions(merge: true));
            return Home();
          } else {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
```

Now, it's broken. There are two errors:

1. *A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User?'.
   Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'User?';*
2. *The property 'uid' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
   Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').*

If I change `User?` to `Object?`, error 2 persists.

**Please send help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `StreamBuilder`, `StreamBuilder<User?>` should be used, like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            User? user = snapshot.data;
            if (user == null) {
              return SignInPage();
            }
            int currentTime = Timestamp.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
            usersReference
                .doc(user.uid)
                .set({"lastLoggedIn": currentTime}, SetOptions(merge: true));
            return Home();
          } else {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `StreamBuilder<User>(...etc`.

and add this before `usersReference.doc(user.uid).set(`

```
if(user!=null) usersReference.doc(user.uid).set({"lastLoggedInCreate": currentTime}, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

This will check if `user` is null or not, and the code will only execute if it's not null, and the error should go away. You have another option of using `user!.uid`, but this isn't advised, as the user might actually be null, causing your function to throw.

Comment: Error 2 persists.

Comment: The thing is user can't be null, that's why I used ```snaphot.data != null``` instead of ```user != null``` in line 7

Comment: Then use the same thing for UID, because that can't be null for sure. If you can garauntee that user is never null, go ahead and use  `!` with user.uid. does it work?